# Is there an option to make Terraform apply incremental? e.g. non-destructive (similar to Azure ARM incremental option)

Tags: terraform

In Azure ARM I can have Infrastructure as code, and using incremental deploy, if someone fat fingers the ARM config (e.g. deletes a VM in the ARM Template), it will not do the deletion (we can do that manually and adjust the ARM template after).

Is there a similar option in Terraform? Looking in stackoverflow it looks not which makes this approach risky for operational use for us (but good for internal environments/demos).

Is there any suitable approach that is lower risk with Terraform? e.g. avoid accidental resource deletions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you mean by "incremental application" but Terraform support applying plan, so what you need to do is:

```
terraform plan -out=plan
```

This will print changes that will be done to your infrastructure and create file `plan` that describes them. After that you can just fire

```
terraform apply plan
```

And this will perform given plan only if the state of the infrastructure haven't changed since plan creation.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about how Azure ARM work, but to avoid accidental deletion, you can use prevent_destroy flag in lifecycle block of required resources/modules.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#lifecycle

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#prevent_destroy

> prevent_destroy (bool) - This flag provides extra protection against
>   the destruction of a given resource. When this is set to true, any
>   plan that includes a destroy of this resource will return an error
>   message.

Comment: NO. You're misunderstanding OP's question. This configuration parameter is not a solution to OP's question in the least, for three reasons:
- 1st, it is for `destroy` operations and not `apply` operations which is what OP is talking about
- 2nd, it prevents the entire plan to run instead of only skipping the flagged resources, which is an actual bug or grave design flaw on the part of the hashicorp team
- 3rd, OP wants to declare resources to be created while leaving the existing resources untouched, which is exactly the **incremental deployment** mode of ARM Templates.